# Why the depth of kernel of first convolutional layer is 48 in AlexNet?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

In AlexNet, the filter size is `5*5*48` in first layer and `3*3*128` in second layer.

Why 48 and 128 are used as depth? Can we change both to different numbers?

[image: AlextNet structure]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The depiction of neural network there could be confusing for some. Actually, layer with 48 dimensions, specifically 5 * 5 * 48 dimensions is the second convolutional layer. From the [article](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf);

> ..The second convolutional layer takes as input the (response-normalized
>   and pooled) output of the first convolutional layer and filters it with 256 kernels of size 5 × 5 × 48

I assumed though, your confusion stem from the first layer was described as 11 * 11 * 96 dimensions but depiction in the image was not. In case you are asking why did the authors chose such size, is still something varies in scientific community as about deciding the parameters of a neural network is somewhat done by intuition (at least by this time).